# Inserting a newline into a pre tag (IE, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, pre

In IE when I insert text into a `<pre>` tag the newlines are ignored:

```
<pre id="putItHere"></pre>

<script>
function putText() {
   document.getElementById("putItHere").innerHTML = "first line\nsecond line";
}
</script>
```

Using `\r\n` instead of a plain `\n` does not work.

`<br/>` does work but inserts an extra blank line in FF, which is not acceptable for my purposes.

Comment: <br /> doesn't add an extra line in Firefox for me.

Comment: Me neither, I guess he left the \n after it hence my answer.

Comment: I thought one of the points of jQuery was to abstract away the differences between browsers and versions.  If i wanted the new (broken) IE behavior I would use `.innerHTML = "..."` instead of `.html("...")`.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These [quirksmode.org bug report and comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2004/11/innerhtml_and_t.html) about innerHTML behaviour of Internet Explorer could help:

"*IE applies **HTML normalization** to the data that is assigned to the innerHTML property. This causes incorrect display of whitespace in elements that ought to preserve formatting, such as <pre> and <textarea>.*"

Answer (score 7):

Does this work in IE?

```
document.getElementById("putItHere")
    .appendChild(document.createTextNode("first line\nsecond line"));
```

I tested it with Firefox and it works. :-)

Comment: Worked like a charm, i needed to do full html injection into a pre tag. I tested all the way back to IE6.

Comment: Helped in my case also and it's a quick fix.

Comment: This worked great for me in IE8, much more elegant than having the Javascript code writing HTML tags.

Comment: It really saves my time, great work!

Answer (score 5):

The workaround can be found in the page linked to in the accepted answer. For ease of use here it is:

```
if (elem.tagName == "PRE" && "outerHTML" in elem)
{
    elem.outerHTML = "<PRE>" + str + "</PRE>";
}
else
{
    elem.innerHTML = str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the relevant part of the link.

Answer (score 4):

`<br/>` shoud only output one line in all browsers. Of course remove the \n as well, code should be:

```
document.getElementById("putItHere").innerHTML = "first line<br/>second line";
```

Answer (score 4):

Content inside the `<pre>` tag should not be considered HTML.

In fact, the point of `<pre>` tag is so that it does display formatted text.

Using the innerText property is the correct way to modify the content of a `<pre>` tag.

```
document.getElementById("putItHere").innerText = "first line\nsecond line";
```

Comment: True, this would work fine in IE, but note that innerText is not available in Firefox - DOM manipulation methods would likely be a more robust solution in this case, such as Chris Jester-Young's answer using appendChild and document.createTextNode.

Answer (score 2):

[IE9 does not normalize white spaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/13/interoperable-html-parsing-in-ie9.aspx), unlike its predecessors.

You should test for support rather than targeting any specific browser. E.g...

```
var t = document.createElement(elem.tagName);
t.innerHTML = "\n";

if( t.innerHTML === "\n" ){
    elem.innerHTML = str;
}
else if("outerHTML" in elem)
{
    elem.outerHTML = "<"+elem.tagName+">" + str + "</"+elem.tagName+">";
}
else {
    // fallback of your choice, probably do the first one.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I reckon this.

What I found was IE is using \r\n and Fx(others) is using \n

```
var newline;
if ( document.all ) newline = '\r\n';
else newline = '\n';

var data = 'firstline' + newline + 'second line';
document.getElementById("putItHere").appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
```

For a TinyMCE(wysiwyg editor) plugin I once made I ended up with using BR i edit mode
and cleaned it up on submit etc.

This code loops through all BR elements inside PRE elements and replaces BR with newlines.

Note that the code relies on the TinyMCE API, but can easily be written using standard Javascript.

Clean up:

```
        var br = ed.dom.select('pre br');
        for (var i = 0; i < br.length; i++) {
          var nlChar;
          if (tinymce.isIE)
            nlChar = '\r\n';
          else
            nlChar = '\n';

          var nl = ed.getDoc().createTextNode(nlChar);
          ed.dom.insertAfter(nl, br[i]);
          ed.dom.remove(br[i]);
        }
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is actually the best solution I've found here. Here is what I ended up with, which actually works incredibly closely to how .innerText works normally. This is what I ended up with:

```element.innerText = "";

element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textContent));```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that innerHTML is processed before it is applied to the element, hence <br> becomes a newline and multiple white spaces are removed.

To preserve the raw text you must use nodeValue, for example;

```
document.getElementById('pre_id').firstChild.nodeValue='    white space \r\n ad new line';
```

Comment: I think that this is a better answer that the accepted one.  The accepted answer does not preserve the attributes in the <pre> tag and doing so would be even more work.

Comment: It turns out that this doesn't work in IE9.  The lesson learned is not to post when tired, frustrated and testing half a dozen browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use outerHTML, you can also do the following for IE, if an additional pre tag is not an issue:

```
 if(isIE)
     document.getElementById("putItHere").innerHTML = "<pre>" + content+"</pre>";
 else
     document.getElementById("putItHere").innerHTML = content;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very small tweak to Edward Wilde's answer that preserves the attributes on the <pre> tag.

```
if (elem.tagName == "PRE" && "outerHTML" in elem) {
    var outer = elem.outerHTML;
    elem.outerHTML = outer.substring(0, outer.indexOf('>') + 1) + str + "</PRE>";
}
else {
    elem.innerHTML = str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof div2.innerText == 'undefined')
    div2.innerHTML = value;
else
    div2.innerText = value;
```

that worked for me.