# Html <pre> not formatting/rendering text correctly

Tags: html, pre

Following code gets correctly formatted in HTML using Pre tag. The break tags get rendered correctly showing line breaks

```
<pre id="code">  package a;<br>import a.b;<br>import d.c;<br>public class Test{<br>}
     </pre>
```

Get the following output -

package a;
import a.b;
import d.c;
public class Test{
}

However if I load the same text using javascript

```
code.innerText = currentQuestion.code;
```

The break tag do not get rendered correctly and are shown as it is -

```
package a;<br>import a.b;<br>import d.c;<br>public class Test{<br>}
```

Can someone please help me here..thanks

Comment: Found the answer in another question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451486/pre-tag-loses-line-breaks-when-setting-innerhtml-in-ie#:~:text=5%20Answers&text=Setting%20innerHTML%20fires%20up%20an,parser%20retains%20the%20hard%20returns.

Comment: You need to set the `innerHTML`, not the `innerText`