# prettify highlightning in a PRE with white-space:nowrap is one line in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, newline, prettify, pre

In Internet Explorer, a `PRE` with a style of `white-space:nowrap` is causing the code in the `PRE` to be in one single line when I use prettify (http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Doesn't a `<br/>` is supposed to cause a new line in a `PRE`? I checked the HTML source generated by prettify after the page has loaded and it generates `<br/>` when it encounter newlines.

See http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2009/12/google-street-view-with-google-maps_27.html for an example.

This doesn't happen in FF nor Chrome.

Thanks

**EDIT:** Maybe this is related to this: [Inserting a newline into a pre tag (IE, Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195363/inserting-a-newline-into-a-pre-tag-ie-javascript)

Comment: Strange thing... your example link doesn't work unless you replace the %5F with an underscore, even though it's identical.

Comment: It's weird.. when I edit the post, the underscore is still there..

Comment: That is weird. I wish I had an answer to your question, I spent a while in the debugger looking at it. It appears to me that there are **no** br tags in the pre block after prettyPrint() has run. Are you sure they are there in IE?

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciated... I found that maybe this is caused by this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195363/inserting-a-newline-into-a-pre-tag-ie-javascript

Comment: Please provide an answer that fixes prettify for my blog :( http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/ I've inspected the content with firebug, and seen it inserts `<br>` but people that use IE reported that it displays all in one line. Something must go wrong -.-

Comment: for me in IE8, the code is on multiple lines, but it does not get prettified at all

Comment: @Kip: Same thing for me in IE6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [The Internet Explorer innerHTML Quirk](http://stud3.tuwien.ac.at/~e0226430/innerHtmlQuirk.html):

> The innerHTML property of HTML
>   elements is well-known and widely
>   used. It is capable of setting the
>   complete content of an element in one
>   go, including elements and the like.
>   As the [QuirksMode
>   tests](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html)
>   have shown, innerHTML is the fastest
>   way to dynamically change the page
>   content.
>
> However, innerHTML has a problem in
>   Internet Explorer.
>
> The HTML standard requires a
>   transformation on display of content.
>   All kinds and amounts of adjacent
>   whitespace are collapsed into a single
>   space. This is a good thing - just as
>   an example, it allows me to add a lot
>   of line breaks into this source file
>   without having to worry about weird
>   line breaks in the displayed text.
>
> Internet Explorer applies these
>   transformations on assignment to the
>   innerHTML property. This seems like a
>   good idea: it saves a little time
>   during display, because if the
>   in-memory representation is already
>   normalized, then the browser doesn't
>   have to normalize whenever it needs to
>   display the text.
>
> There are exceptions to the
>   normalization rule, though. Notably,
>   these are the `<textarea>` element,
>   the `<pre>` element and, in CSS-aware
>   browsers, elements with any value but
>   normal for the white-space property.
>
> Internet Explorer does not respect
>   these special cases. The third makes
>   their optimization a bad idea, because
>   white-space might change at runtime,
>   for example through the DOM. In any
>   case, Internet Explorer will normalize
>   all assignments to the innerHTML
>   property.

This is another IE only "bug" (even if it's them who invented innerHTML). In the first link you have solutions to this problem but as Lucas pointed out all seems to point at code by Google which you have no control over.

Answer (score 2):

Hey litb, you're right, in versions IE6 and IE7 the `pre` tag code is displayed on 1 line. I've added this small fix for browsers IE6 and 7 only.

I've tested it and it works fine, it's a bit hacky because I'm actually replacing `<br>` tags with `<p>` tags, but this doesn't cause any visual difference in the IE6 and 7 browsers.

You can add this snippet of code anywhere on your HTML page. It's using jQuery.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // this BR issue seems to happen only in browser
    // msie version 6.0 and 7.0
    if($.browser.msie && ($.browser.version == "6.0" || $.browser.version == "7.0")) {

        // replace all <br>s in the .prettyprint section
        // with <p> tags. <p> tags have the same visual behavior as <br> tags
        // in IE 6 and 7
        $(".prettyprint br").each(function(){
            $(this).replaceWith($("<p></p>"));
        });

    }

});
</script>
```

This is probably your best option until google fixes their prettify code for IE6 & 7.