# Text document loading only first line in pre tag in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Same text document loads perfectly fine in chrome browser but loading only first line in internet explorer.

here is the text document

[image]

here is the code, I am loading the content in pre tag as following.

```
<pre style="background-color: white; ">{{content}}</pre>
```

But in Internet explorer it shows like this

[image]

In chrome it works perfectly fine

[image]

Note: red dot in image represents /u0. how to remove this from text content?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195363/inserting-a-newline-into-a-pre-tag-ie-javascript

Comment: @CarolMcKay is there alternative way using css, to fix this issue?

Comment: @user3660375,In IE you need to keep your content in single line in text file. You can use \n and \t to format the text for Internet Explorer. Then it will display in new line and in proper format in IE. You can directly try to add it in your text file.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I am geeting text file from the server, which cannot be formatted or replaced.The problem is IE doesnt add a new line for pre and textarea. do you mind providing any solution for this.

Comment: @user3660375, I did not get any solution with pre tag. You can try to use any other tag like span or div to display the text file to check whether it display the file correctly or not.